# Bash append a list to end element of array

Tags: arrays, bash, list, append

I am attempting to add a list to the end of a bash array that already contains elements, the array contains {a..z} and I want to add {0..9} to the end of that list, I've attempted += and this doesn't work it clears the array in my case.

```
while [ ! $# -eq 0 ] # Argument selector for CLI input
    do
        case "$1" in
            --num | -n)
                chars=( {0..9} )
                ;;
            --char | -c)
                chars=( {a..z} )
                ;;
            --upper-char | -C)
                chars=( {A..Z} )
                ;;
            --help | -h)
                echo "Type the program name with an argument -n for numbers -c for lowercase char and -C for uppercase"
                exit
                ;;
        esac
        case "$2" in
            --num | -n)
                chars[${#chars[@]}]=( {0..9} )
                ;;
            --char | -c
                chars[${#chars[@]}]=( {a..z} )
                ;;
            --upper-char | -C)
                chars[${#chars[@]}]=( {A..Z} )
                ;;

        esac
        shift
    done
```

I'm hoping to do a third case statement once I've worked out how to append lists, best case scenario is not having to hard code the array every time I want to add items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Appending to an array *does* work with `+=`.
To you it appeared to be overwriting because of some other mistake in the code. This should work:

```
while [ ! $# -eq 0 ] # Argument selector for CLI input
do
    case "$1" in
        --num | -n)
            chars=( {0..9} )
            ;;
        --char | -c)
            chars=( {a..z} )
            ;;
        --upper-char | -C)
            chars=( {A..Z} )
            ;;
        --help | -h)
            echo "Type the program name with an argument -n for numbers -c for lowercase char and -C for uppercase"
            exit
            ;;
    esac
    case "$2" in
        --num | -n)
            chars+=( {0..9} )
            ;;
        --char | -c)
            chars+=( {a..z} )
            ;;
        --upper-char | -C)
            chars+=( {A..Z} )
            ;;
    esac
    shift 2
done
```

When it didn't work for you,
I suspect you had just `shift` instead of `shift 2`,
and expected that `script.sh -c -n` would give you `a..z` and `0..9`,
but it only gave `0..9`.
What happened is after just one `shift`,
one argument still remained to process in the `while` loop,
and so in the next iteration `chars` got replaced with a `chars=(...)` statement.

I propose this alternative implementation:

```
chars=()
while [ $# != 0 ]; do
    case "$1" in
        --num | -n)
            chars+=( {0..9} )
            ;;
        --char | -c)
            chars+=( {a..z} )
            ;;
        --upper-char | -C)
            chars+=( {A..Z} )
            ;;
        --help | -h)
            echo "Type the program name with an argument -n for numbers -c for lowercase char and -C for uppercase"
            exit 1
            ;;
    esac
    shift
done
```

Comment: adding extra cases is fine now '     case "$2" in
          --num | -n)
               chars+=( {0..9} )
              ;;
          --char | -c)
             chars+=( {a..z} )
             ;;
         --upper-char | -C)
             chars+=( {A..Z} )
             ;;
     esac
 case "$3" in
          --num | -n)
             chars+=( {0..9} )
              ;;
          --char | -c)
             chars+=( {a..z} )
             ;;
         --upper-char | -C)
             chars+=( {A..Z} )
             ;;
     esac
    shift 3
done'

Comment: I've also changed the first section to be an append rather than an equals like you suggested, thank you !

Comment: @user3019354 you don't need 3 `case`, one is enough, as in my last suggestion.